# Fetch page data in background while returning current page

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

In the code below I have a pull_data function which calls the main function `fetch_data` to get a page data.

To make fetching faster and store data beforehand I have used `call_thread_func` to fetch a few more pages during the current page fetch.

Issue is currently pull data calls both function sequentially and then returns, which makes UI to wait for the data.

I want it to work like: when I call pull data it should call `fetch_data` for the current page and return page data and in the background it should fetch other pages by calling `call_thread_func`.

Let me know if you guys have any questions.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

class Fetch: 
    def __init__(self,page_num):
        self.page_num = page_num
        self.table_rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        self.return_list = [[] for _ in range(len(self.table_rows))]

    def fetch_data(self,page_num):
        print("start..")
        #fetching data
        time.sleep(1)
        print("completed..")
        #storing fetched data in to return list index
        self.return_list[page_num-1] = F"DATA-{page_num}"
        print(f"completed fetch for page: {page_num}")


    def call_thread_func(self):
        #get other +2, -2 pages from cureent page            
        thread_lst = [self.page_num-2, self.page_num-1, self.page_num+1, self.page_num+2]
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as excutor:
            futures = [excutor.submit(self.fetch_data,thread) for thread in thread_lst]
            print("..checking futuers now..")
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                print(future.result())

    # api call function          
    def pull_data(self):
        self.fetch_data(self.page_num)
        self.call_thread_func()
        return {
            "Data": self.return_list
        }
        
data = Fetch(5)

print(data.pull_data())
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to load one page and 2 *surrounding* pages around it from left/right. If the one page is loaded, return immediately while the surrounding pages load in the background.

This example will use `fetched_pages` dictionary to store loaded pages. Main function will create 4 workers (threads) which share one common `Queue`. From main thread I put data into queue and when any page is loaded the workers will use `Condition` to notify main thread.

```py
import threading, queue, time

q = queue.Queue()
cv = threading.Condition()

fetched_pages = {}


def fetch_page_worker():
    while True:
        page_num = q.get()

        with cv:
            # is page already loaded?
            if page_num in fetched_pages:
                q.task_done()
                cv.notify()
                continue

        # load page...
        time.sleep(1)

        with cv:
            fetched_pages[page_num] = "Loaded..."
            q.task_done()
            cv.notify()


def main():
    # create workers
    workers = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_page_worker) for _ in range(4)]
    # start workers
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    while True:
        print("Already loaded pages:", fetched_pages)

        try:
            page_num = int(input("Please enter page num:"))
        except ValueError:
            continue

        for page in range(page_num - 2, page_num + 2):
            q.put(page)

        # only wait for page_num to be loaded
        with cv:
            while page_num not in fetched_pages:
                cv.wait()
            print(fetched_pages[page_num])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you run the program and enter for example `10`, the program will wait one second to load it. When you enter `10` again, the program will print the page immediately (because is already loaded - the same with 8, 9, 11, 12).

Sample output:

```
Already loaded pages: {}
Please enter page num:10
Loaded...
Already loaded pages: {8: 'Loaded...', 9: 'Loaded...', 10: 'Loaded...', 11: 'Loaded...'}
Please enter page num:8
Loaded...
Already loaded pages: {8: 'Loaded...', 9: 'Loaded...', 10: 'Loaded...', 11: 'Loaded...'}
Please enter page num:
Already loaded pages: {8: 'Loaded...', 9: 'Loaded...', 10: 'Loaded...', 11: 'Loaded...', 6: 'Loaded...', 7: 'Loaded...'}
Please enter page num:
```

Comment: is threading.Condition() functionality is available in concurrent.futures module ?

Comment: @Adam I'm not aware that functionality in `concurrent.futures`